# Recursive CTE in SQL Server last node

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have the following table in SQL Server :

```
| id | Name    | ParentId |    
| 1  | world   | Null     |
| 2  | Region  | 1        |
| 3  | Country | 2        |
| 4  | State   | 3        |
| 5  | City    | 4        |
| 6  | Street  | 5        |
```

The number of hierarchies is not fixed.

I need an output in the form of Street, City, State, Country, Region, world.

Running the following SQL code :

```
WITH Hierarchy (ChildId, ChildName, ParentId, Childs) AS
(
    SELECT 
        Id, Name, ParentId, CAST('' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM 
        UserType AS LastGeneration
    WHERE 
        Id NOT IN (SELECT COALESCE(ParentId, 0) FROM UserType)  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        PrevGeneration.Id, PrevGeneration.Name, PrevGeneration.ParentId,
        CAST(CASE WHEN Child.Childs = ''
                     THEN(CAST(Child.ChildName AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
                     ELSE(Child.Childs + ', ' + CAST(Child.ChildName AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
        END AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    FROM 
        UserType AS PrevGeneration
    INNER JOIN 
        Hierarchy AS Child ON PrevGeneration.Id = Child.ParentId  
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

This returns an output of:

```
Street, City, State, Country, Region
```

What do I need to add to the recursion to get the last node?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Going from leaves up to the root will produce many duplicates (cause one parent may have lots of children) - better use from top to bottom approach (1st cte in Ed's answer). In your code I guess you have to concat `PrevGeneration.Name` instead of `Child.ChildName`. With concatenating of ChildName you leave no chances to the root level since it is not child to any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different solutions - one works from the top down, the other from the bottom up. The top-down solution is a little more efficient. I'm not sure exactly what output you want for the intermediate rows, so I'm posting both.

```
DECLARE @usertype TABLE
(id int, Name varchar(20),ParentId int)

INSERT @usertype
VALUES (1 ,'world',Null),(2 ,'Region',1),(3 ,'Country',2),  
(4 ,'State',3), (5 ,'City',4),(6 ,'Street',5);   


-- Top down
WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS name_hierarchy
    FROM @UserType
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.Id, u.name, u.ParentId, u.name + ', ' + r.name_hierarchy
    FROM recCTE AS r
    JOIN @usertype AS u
    ON u.ParentId = r.Id
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE;

--Bottom up
WITH recCTE2
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS name_hierarchy
    FROM @usertype AS u1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @usertype AS u2 WHERE u1.Id = u2.ParentId)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT u.Id, u.name, u.ParentId,  r.name_hierarchy+ ', ' + u.name 
    FROM recCTE2 AS r
    JOIN @usertype AS u
    ON r.ParentId = u.Id
)
SELECT * FROM recCTE2;
```

Your code has some additional complexity which appeared unnecessary, based on the information you've posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!